# Horizontal scrollbar in a container with fixed size

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have got a container with a **fixed size** with a **wider** child.

I don't want to scroll the whole document. I just want to scroll the child in the **x-axis**.

```css
.banner {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS `overflow: hidden`  property on the `body`, so "the whole document" is not x-scrollable, and set `overflow-x: scroll` on the `.banner`, so it is x-scrollable:

```css
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
}

.banner {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<p>
   A paragraph of text to separate from the horizontal scrollbar
</p>
```

Comment: There are a few problems with this. There should be no need to set overflow hidden on the body in this case as no element should overflow from the body (and really hiding the body overflow isn't a particularly good idea anyway since it can mess up with the rest of the document). What you're doing is hiding an issue instead of fixing it. This means that you can't see the end of the blue and red element as they currently overflow from the body.

Comment: Also I assume there should be space on the right of the red div as there is on its left, which can't happen with the current implementation.